# How to generate translation file for a custom Drupal 7 module?

Tags: drupal, localization, internationalization, gettext, drupal-7

I'm using CentOS 5.5 Linux (without X), PHP 5.3 and Drupal 7.0.

The core language of my site is Russian (not English)!

I've created a **game.info** and the following **game.module** which generates 3 blocks for the front page:

```
function game_block_info() {
  return array(
  'game_main' => array(
    'info' => t('Set FlashVars and show the flash game.'),
    'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
  ),
  'game_winner' => array(
    'info' => t('Show the winner of the last week.'),
    'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
  ),
  'game_leader' => array(
    'info' => t('Show the leader of the current week.'),
    'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
  );
}


function game_block_view($block_name = '') {
  global $user;

  if ($block_name == 'game_main') {
    if (user_is_logged_in()) {
      $content = t('User is logged in.');
    } else {
      $content = t('User is an anonymous user.');
    }
    drupal_set_message("<pre>$output</pre>\n");
    return array(
      'subject' => t('Main Game'),
      'content' => $content,
    );
  } else if ($block_name == 'game_winner') {
    ....
  } else if ($block_name == 'game_leader') {
    ....
  }
}
```

It works ok, but I need all strings to be in Russian and do not want to hardcode them into my game.module file.

Do I need to create the 3rd file called **game.po** and add it to the game.info?

How can I create a .po file? I would prefer a simple editing of that file if possible, without obscure tools.

I've also tried a tool:

```
# xgettext -n game/game.module --keyword=t
xgettext: warning: file `game/game.module' extension `module' is unknown; will try C
game/game.module:87: warning: unterminated character constant
game/game.module:100: warning: unterminated character constant
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

These should be the steps:

1. To generate the .pot file, install the module [Translation template extractor](http://drupal.org/project/potx)
2. Go to the "*Extract strings*" tab on the Locale administration interface, select your module and submit the form. You will get one single template file generated.
3. Then you can translate the strings with a tool like **Poedit** (http://www.poedit.net).
4. When you are done, files should be copied to a "translations" sub-folder in the module folder, so they are automatically imported by Drupal when installing your game module.

Please, give feedback and tell what problems did you have. Thanks

Comment: Not that although this is all correct, for contributed modules, the extraction of localization strings happens automatically when a new version is released by http://localize.drupal.org. Then, http://drupal.org/project/l10n_update can be used to get the translations from there. But custom modules are a different story, obviously...

Comment: If you are translating a *custom* module, you need to *reinstall* it in order to apply translation. When you don't want to do that (e.g. you don't want to lost all permissions and db tables on uninstall) you can run a drush command to force translations loading: ``drush php-eval "locale_system_update(array('yourmodule_name'));drush_backend_batch_process();"``

Comment: @corbacho: i follow your steps but it didn't work for me